# How to compose HTML Body from a Mosaico Template content?

Tags: civimail, api, email, mosaico

I amb creating a Mailing via API calls. I dynamically create the Moisaico code. But when the Email gets created, it doesn't have any HTML code, so I can not send it. How can I get the HTML code from the Mosaico code?

If I go through the CiviCRM web GUI, I just need to click on "Edit" on the Mosaico Design created for that Email, and then jsut click "Save" or "Close", and the HTML gets created by Mosaico and then I can send the email.

How can I make this process via API?

Thanks.

Comment: anynone has any idea about this issue? I tried to send the HTML code made by myself, but it's too long and I receive a "401 URI Too long" error...

Comment: Can you add some details on what api call you tried ? Is it in REST, php or javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - this should serve your needs

Mosaico Message Templates
For each "Mosaico Template", automatically create "Message Templates" for use in scheduled reminders, personal emails, etc.

https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.mosaicomsgtpl